# Query to find whether a table was updated within a specific time period

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Table1 

Emp_no|| end_date || col2 || Sent date
```

This table will send the details of a particular employee and the sent date column will be updated as sysdate whenever the detail is entered in this table.

Now for the second run ill have to check that was the mail sent for the same employee within 15 days ? if yes then the row will not be updated in the table1. i.e. i have to compare the latest sent date and sysdate. For this i am using a function

```
create or replace Function last_mail_sent(p_emp_no number,pay_period_end_date date)
return number
is
begin

select trunc(sysdate)-trunc(sent_date)
into
l_days
from table1
where emp_no=p_emp_no
and sent_date=(select max(sent_date) from tabl1
                                where emp_no=p_emp_no
                                and trunc(end_date)=trunc(pay_period_end_date );
exception when no_data_found
then
l_days :=0;
else
when others then
l_days:=-1;
end;


return l_days;
end;
/
```

The logic i was trying to use in the package where i have used this funcn to decide whether or not to insert was :

```
l_last_mail_sent := last_mail_sent(pass the parameter by fetching cols from cursor)


if l_last_mail_sent=0 (That is no row is fetched from the function)
or l_last_mail_sent>15
then
insert into Table1 
else
--do not insert

end if;
```

But the problem with the above query is . that for example if the table was updated today the sent_date column was updated with todays date then also the function will return 0. Is there a better logic that can be formed ? P.S :-I have to create a function to deal with this as this will be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc(sysdate) - trunc(max(sent_date))
into l_days
from table1
where emp_no = p_emp_no
  and end_date between trunc(pay_period_end_date) and trunc(pay_period_end_date) + 1 - 1/24/60/60;
```

(This query won't raise any exceptions so you don't need to catch anything)
I've changed the condition a bit so you can use an index on an end_date (if any)

And then

```
if l_last_mail_sent is null or l_last_mail_sent > 15 then
--insert into Table1 
else
--do not insert
end if;
```

Comment: Hi i did not get the and end_date between trunc(pay_period_end_date) and trunc(pay_period_end_date) + 1 - 1/24/60/60 part. y is this required ?

Comment: No, you can leave your version: "trunc(end_date)=trunc(pay_period_end_date )"

Comment: trunc(pay_period_end_date) + 1 - 1/24/60/60 - date with the time 23:59:59